# Flask + Nginx. flask redirect

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Есть ссылка http://mydomain.com/flask/site1/ и flask сайт http://mydomain.com:5000.

Чтобы первая ссылка переотправляла из nginx во flask используется proxy:

```
location ~* /flask/site1/(.*) {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

Все работает хорошо до тех пор пока из flask не используется, к примеру

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Редирект происходит на http://mydomain.com/index/
Как можно настроить flask или nginx так, чтобы редирект происходил на ссылку "http://mydomain.com/flask/site1/index" ?

P.S. url_for('index', _external=True) не помогает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441